how to get the refresh token once a user logs in?
Here is my scenario I want to implement :

User goes on the site page, on arrival on a protected page he is redirected to log in using oauth2.
Once the server receives a new connection, it stores, if required, the refresh token
Later on, if needed, a @scheduled taks fetch the interesting data from the distant server and store them in the DB using the refresh token.

I was able to configure oauth2 correctly :

application.yaml contains a spring.security.oauth2.client.provider and a registration using that provider.
I added a bean to configure the security :

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

Now when I fetch localhost:8080/ I have no issue, if I fetch eg localhost:8080/user it redirects correctly to oauth then I can access the resource.

I added another service to intercept the conect :

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))
public class Oauth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);
        return processOAuth2User(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2User);
    }

    private OAuth2User processOAuth2User(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        System.out.println("user attributes : " + oAuth2User.getAttributes());
        System.out.println("access token is " + oAuth2UserRequest.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
        System.out.println(
                "refresh token is : " + oAuth2UserRequest.getAdditionalParameters().get(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN));
        System.out.println(
                "additional parameters are : " + oAuth2UserRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
        return oAuth2User;
    }
}

However when I do that I only retrieve the access token, which has a short expires and therefore is not suitable for long term udpates. The refresh token is null, the additional parameters are empty map.
I tried several (a lot) of user configuration things, but nothing seems to work (I did not keep a track of it because I've been trying for days now).
Including https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548497/23229663
So here are my question :

Do you have any remark of something that I did bad so far ? It seems to me that spring evolves so fast that something I found may be obsolete 2 years later, typically the @Autowired . Basically plz review :D
How can I get that refresh token ? I tried shenanigans that involve creating a converter in the httpRequest.oauth2login() config, did not work. Maybe I did it bad ? Also other example did not compile
this is a different question, my code should go in a library, but so far I need to create in each library MyLib a MyLibRefence class with @Configuration , @componentScan etc. and annotate my main app class with

@Import({
        MyLibReference1.class,
        MyLibReference2.class})

Could you redirect me to a guide to not have that required anymore ? That is, when I declare my lib as a maven dependency of my MainApp project, it automatically scans for the packages of that lib. I found some clues but I think I got lost. That's low priority though, so far it's tedious but it works. (But since it's tedious it will create bugs later)
4. Also not important, not high priority, how can I store the provider in a library instead of having to write in in the application.yaml ?
Thank you for your time :)
Links :
actual code where I want to implement this : https://github.com/guiguilechat/JCELechat/tree/mevetic/programs/spring/mevetic
Example of main class and imports : https://github.com/guiguilechat/JCELechat/blob/mevetic/programs/spring/eveproxy/src/main/java/fr/guiguilechat/jcelechat/programs/spring/eveproxy/EveProxyApp.java
Example of library Libreference : https://github.com/guiguilechat/JCELechat/blob/mevetic/libs/spring/mer/src/main/java/fr/guiguilechat/jcelechat/libs/spring/mer/MerReference.java
edit : I worked again on the other solution and could make it work.
For reference, here is the code that works, added on the SecurityConfig :
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

// actually no change on the filterChain because it's not needed

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();

        OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setAccessTokenResponseConverter(new CustomTokenResponseConverter());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

        accessTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    public static class CustomTokenResponseConverter implements
            Converter<Map<String, Object>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> {

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse convert(Map<String, Object> tokenResponseParameters) {
            String accessToken = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            String refreshToken = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN);
            Object expiresInObj = tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN);
            long expiresIn = ((Number) expiresInObj).longValue();

            Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();
            if (tokenResponseParameters.containsKey(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)) {
                String scope = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE);
                scopes = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(scope, " "))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }

            return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessToken)
                    .tokenType(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER)
                    .expiresIn(expiresIn)
                    .scopes(scopes)
                    .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                    .additionalParameters(Map.of(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken))
                    .build();
        }
    }

}

The issue I had is that in the code of the other answer, the expiresIn is parsed from string, but with the present framework it is a number (I guess long)  in the map, so the parseLong was failing silently and I just received an error.
That being said, I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it. Especially, it seems like there are several manual configurations that will prevent auto config that would work otherwise.

okay here is the answer for the first one : Just need to have the @Bean for the OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient in a configuration class :
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

// actually no change on the filterChain because it's not needed

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();

        OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setAccessTokenResponseConverter(new CustomTokenResponseConverter());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Arrays.asList(
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(), tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter));
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());

        accessTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    public static class CustomTokenResponseConverter implements
            Converter<Map<String, Object>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> {

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse convert(Map<String, Object> tokenResponseParameters) {
            String accessToken = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            String refreshToken = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN);
            Object expiresInObj = tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.EXPIRES_IN);
            long expiresIn = ((Number) expiresInObj).longValue();

            Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();
            if (tokenResponseParameters.containsKey(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)) {
                String scope = (String) tokenResponseParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE);
                scopes = Arrays.stream(StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(scope, " "))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }

            return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessToken)
                    .tokenType(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER)
                    .expiresIn(expiresIn)
                    .scopes(scopes)
                    .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                    .additionalParameters(Map.of(OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken))
                    .build();
        }
    }

}

The issues I had, were that the signature has been changed and the cast I made were wrong with silent discarding in spring. Once I debugged using sysout I traced the issue to a classcastException.
Here is the answer for the library : Don't even think of the old factories thing. Now you just

Create a Configuration class for your library with @AutoConfigure
Create a src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file that contains the list of fully named class to autoconfigure, newline separated. In that case, that would be my.package.SecurityConfig

No need to import specific autoconfig-parser dependency in maven, no need for @import in the main class. As long as that dependency is imported in maven, spring will use it as autoconfig when starting the container.
Right now it does not work, I guess I have to force my class to be loaded before the oauth2 autoconfig to provide the bean. Will edit later.
edit : it works, I had the file named wrong. No need to @AutoconfigureBefore
